# "непрошено" или "непрошенно"?

Tags: орфография, наречия

Возник вопрос, сколько букв Н писать в наречии "непроше(Н, НН)о.
В словаре под ред. Ефремовой прочла, что вариант "непрошено" - просторечный. Тогда возникает вопрос, если "непрошеный" пишется с одной Н (например, "непрошеный гость"), то почему наречие в литературной норме с двумя? Или нужен контекст, чтобы понять, от какого слова образовано наречие? Может ведь быть и причастие? Например, непрошенный никем гость.

Вот предложение, в котором мне нужно верно написать это слово:

"Слёзы непроше(н, нн)о навернулись на глаза".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Комментарий к ответу**

1. Про наречие ***«непрошено»*** все верно: словари, примеры  из литературы. Но вот последнее замечание неожиданно вызвало вопросы…

Сомнительно сочетание ***«никем не прошенный»***. В Нацкорпусе его можно найти в старых тестах, но правильно ли сейчас так писать, да и говорить тоже?  Слово не слух уже непривычное, хотя и возможное, а вот насколько такое написание соответствует **современным правилам письма?**

2. **Орфографический словарь** (две формы): непрошеный, прил. (непрошеный гость); не прошенный, прич. (Почему форма "не прошенный" дана в словаре с частицей НЕ?)

**Большой толковый словарь**: НЕПРОШЕНЫЙ 1. Явившийся без приглашения; незваный. Н. гость, посетитель. 2. Ненужный, нежелательный для кого-л. Н-ое внимание, сочувствие. Н-ое вторжение. Н-ая помощь. 3. Невольный. Н-ые слёзы. Н-ая улыбка. <**Непрошено, нареч**. Н. явиться. Н. бросился помогать.

В словарях закреплена форма прилагательного «***непрошеный***». Форма «***не прошенный***» — это причастие, слово есть в орфографическом словаре РАН именно в таком виде, но в толковом словаре его нет.

3. Казалось бы, надо использовать форму прилагательного: ***никем не прошеный***. Хотя вот Грамота.ру думает иначе (см. Приложение).

Откуда вообще берется "***никем не прошенный***" или это замена форме "***никем не прошеный***"? Ведь усилительные слова могут использоваться и с прилагательными (перехода в причастие нет), и при этом не считаются они **зависимыми словами**.

Встречается "не прошенный" **в старых текстах** (в обособленном и необособленном виде), но эти тексты не нормированы. Другими словами, одни проблемы для пользователей от этой формы. Где и кто ее применяет?

Да и похоже ли слово на причастие (которое обозначает  действия как признак). Действие глагола "просить" как-то "неотчетливо" здесь выражено, значение скорее **переносное**.

**Приложение**

(1) **Вопрос № 214702** Как правильно писать слово непроше(н,нн)? В "Орфографическом словаре русского языка" п / ред. Лопатина (, М.; Русский язык, 1991) указано «непрошенный», а в "Орфоэпическом словаре" (М.; Русския язык, 1983) — непрошеный.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Правильно: ***непрошеный*** (прилагательное, например: непрошеный гость), но: ***не прошенный*** (причастие, например: он приходил к нам домой, **никем не прошенный**).

(2) **Ольга Славникова**. Стрекоза, увеличенная до размеров собаки (1995-1999)
*Но Софья Андреевна… решительно не пустила в квартиру портативную машинку «Москва», которую Маргарита одолжила бессрочно и бесплатно и даже притащила лично в один из тех дождливых, нудных выходных, когда человек в подъезде неприятен своей смиренной темнотой, запахом мокрой ткани, а освещенный из прихожей, кажется уже **непрошено вошедшим** в унылый уют бесконечного дня.*

(Известный автор, считается образцом в прозе и многим нравится, но читать трудно. Поэтому я к ней отношусь осторожно —  синтаксис сложный, тяжелый. Но стиль, вероятно, такой, ну и темы соответствующие...)

(3) **М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин.** **Святочный рассказ (1858)**
*Прежде всех, как водится, влетел **никем не прошенный** клуб морозного воздуха и мигом наполнил комнату белесоватым туманом…*

(4) **Н. С. Лесков. Детские годы** **(1874)**
Это были общие характеристики, но вслед за тем Пенькновский появлялся к нам от времени до времени, **никем не прошенный**, сообщал нам скандалы частного свойства...

(5) 2. Ф. Е. Зарин-Несвицкий. За чужую свободу (1910)
― Но все же, ― резко сказал князь, вставая, ― я чужой здесь, **не прошенный** гость.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon! Вы всегда очень развёрнуто отвечаете. Примеры, приведённые вами, несколько развеяли мои сомнения. 
Но я всё-таки до конца не поняла, как относиться к этому разночтению. Старая норма ведь ещё действует? И как понять, от причастия или прилагательного образовано это наречие, если ни того, ни другого в тексте нет? Вы бы сами как написали такое наречие? )

Comment: Спасибо за вопрос. Я смотрю в толковый словарь на Грамоте.ру.  Там есть статья для прилагательного «непрошеный», а также указано наречие «непрошено». Это именно прилагательное,  а причастие – это особая форма глагола (надо смотреть статью для глагола «просить»). Смотрю в орфографический словарь РАН, там разрешена форма «непрошеный». Смотрю в Нацкорпус,  там наречие  «непрошено» встречается часто. Этого вполне достаточно, чтобы выбрать именно этот вариант, так что старая форма действует. И как я думаю, является основной.

Comment: А что там с причастием? А там  одни проблемы, а частотность употребления слова, можно сказать, никакая. Тем не менее этот факт смущает пользователей, приводит к вопросам. Но можно ради интереса посмотреть: ПРОСИТЬ 4. (кого-что). Приглашать, звать. П. гостей к столу. П. в гости. П. на обед. П. на чашку кофе. П. в кабинет.  Глагол требует обязательного распространителя: прошенный к столу. Но мы эту форму используем как самостоятельную, и она имеет уже переносное значение: непрошеный – это нежелательный (прил.).

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ и за то, что потратили на него время. 
Странно, почему в толковом словаре Ефремовой присутствуют два варианта, причём вариант с одной Н считается просторечным. Конечно, словарь РАН предпочтительней. Оказывается, всё нужно проверять.

Comment: Словарей много... В сложных случаях удобно обратиться  к практике письма. Вариант с НН практически не встречается.

Answer (score 1):

Прилагательное "непрошеный" и соответствующее наречие пишется с одним н, согласно правилу. Прилагательное образовано от глагола несовершенного вида, не имеет ни приставки, кроме "не", ни зависимых слов. В наречиях же пишется столько н, сколько было в производящей основе, в данном случае в прилагательном.

Но: никем не прошенный гость - причастие с зависимыми словами.

Comment: Хорошо. А если в моём тексте нет ни прилагательного, ни причастия - есть только наречие. Как понять, от чего оно образовано и сколько Н писать?

"Слёзы непроше(н, нн)о навернулись на глаза".

Comment: При чем тут есть или нет. Наречие "непрошено" образовано от прилагательного "непрошеный". Поэтому одна н.

Comment: А почему оно не может быть образовано от причастия?

Comment: @Татьяна, нет причастия непрошенный.Оно употребляется только в контексте.